# Mandatory Tags for DICOM Instance

Tags: dicom

I am trying send a DICOM instance (an image in my case) from an application to a server.
But somehow it is not Happening.

The logs reveals that some tags were missing.

So what is the list of mandatory tags which are required during a DICOM association (a C-STORE in my case) ?

Comment: This is a wage question. Be specific which service you are using and what is make of server and application.

Answer (score 13):

Which tags are mandatory is a function of what SOP class is used to represent the image.  It varies.  There are tables in part 3 of the DICOM standard (available at ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/2009/) which tell you which modules are required.  Other documentation for individual tags will tell you if they are Type 1, 1C, 2, 2C, or 3.  The Type 3 attributes are optional.  The types with a C are mandatory under certain conditions and not mandatory under other conditions.  Type 1 is always mandatory and must have a valid value.  Type 2 is required to exist but can have a null value.

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for giving answer..i want to know which file i have to choose in that directory..

Comment: 09_03pu3 is DICOM part 3, 09_06pu3 is DICOM part 6, etc.  Part 3 is the main thing you need to look at, but part 6 (the data dictionary) will also be helpful for figuring out the value multiplicities (some DICOM tags encode a sequence of values instead of just one value).

Answer (score 1):

If you use dcm4chee, there is a dcm4chee/server/default/conf/dcm4chee-attribute-filter.xml with DTD stating following:

`Minimal descriptor for DICOM Standard Conformance of Query/Retrieve Service:
  <dcm4chee-attribute-filter>
    <patient>
      <attr tag="00080005"/>
      <attr tag="00100010"/>
      <attr tag="00100020"/>
    </patient>`

```
<study>
  <attr tag="00080005"/>
  <attr tag="00080020"/>
  <attr tag="00080030"/>
  <attr tag="00080050"/>
  <attr tag="0020000D"/>
  <attr tag="00200010"/>
</study>

<series>
  <attr tag="00080060"/>
  <attr tag="0020000E"/>
  <attr tag="00200011"/>
</series>

<instance>
  <attr tag="00080018"/>
  <attr tag="00200013"/>
</instance>
```

</dcm4chee-attribute-filter>

While Matt's answer is absolutely correct, this should get you started faster.

Comment: Hi Alex Pakka thanks for giving reply....i have to know which file i have to select in Matt given answer ..there are so many files in that directory...

Comment: DICOM CHE is not standard. Provide answer in DICOM Standard.

Comment: @Satbir: there is no word about standard in the question. I understood it like "I have an app that does DICOM C-MOVE, however,  PACS server does not accept my studies. Help me get over it fast?" I assume people read and understand DICOM standard before undertaking those things. IF the PACS server happened to be dcm4che, this would have solved the problem. I don't think downgrade was justified.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending an DICOM image to server means it is C-STORE, so the server(PACS) which you are using checks for the Transfer syntax UID and also Some Header SOP Instance UID and Class UID, check your dicom tags whether the above stated tags are filled.